# cannot connect with firebase and firestore with flutter + bloc pattern

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-bloc

repository.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AnswersRepository {
  getAnswers() async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("answers").get()
        .then((querySnapshot) {
      for (var result in querySnapshot.docs) {
       return result.data();
        print("SSSSSSSSSSSSSSS ${result.data()}");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

the state

```
class AnswersSuccessState extends AnswersState {
  Map<String, dynamic> answers;
  AnswersSuccessState({required this.answers});
}
```

the bloc

```
class AnswersBloc extends Bloc<AnswersEvent, AnswersState> {
  final AnswersRepository repo;
  AnswersBloc(this.repo) : super(AnswersLoadingState()) {
    on<AnswersEvent>((event, emit) async{
      emit(AnswersLoadingState());
      try {
        final answers = await repo.getAnswers();
        emit(AnswersSuccessState(answers: answers));
      }catch(e) {
        emit(AnswersErrorState(msg: e.toString()));
      }
    });
  }

}
```

main.dart

```
    void main() {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      runApp( MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      final fb = Firebase.initializeApp();
       MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Quick Answers',
          theme: ThemeData(
            brightness: Brightness.light,
            primaryColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
            fontFamily: 'Georgia',
          ),
          home: Scaffold(
            body: FutureBuilder(
              future: fb,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.hasError) {
                  print(snapshot.error);
                  return const Center(child: Text("something wrong",
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),),);
                } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return RepositoryProvider<AnswersRepository>(
                    create: (context) => AnswersRepository(),
                    child: MultiBlocProvider(
                        providers: [
                          BlocProvider<AnswersBloc>(
                              create: (context)
                              => AnswersBloc(context.read<AnswersRepository>())
                                ..add(FetchAnswers()))
                        ],
                        child: HomeScreen()
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                }
        }),
          )
        );
      }
    }
```

UI

```
  child: BlocConsumer<AnswersBloc, AnswersState>(
          listener: (context, state) {},
          builder: (context, state) {
            if(state is AnswersLoadingState) {
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
            } else if(state is AnswersSuccessState) {
              GridView.builder(
                  itemCount: 20,
                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2) ,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return CardWidget(
                        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                         title: state.answers[index].title,
                          link: state.answers[index].link,);
                  }
              );
            } else if(state is AnswersErrorState) {
              return Center(child: Text(state.msg),);
            }
            return Container();
          } ,
        )
```

show me this error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55327/MSL098hcqm4=/ws
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86...
W/DynamiteModule(24240): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule(24240): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller(24240): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/s.quick_answer(24240): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/s.quick_answer(24240): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/TetheringManager(24240): registerTetheringEventCallback:osama.atraqchi.answers.quick_answers
V/NativeCrypto(24240): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 295 native methods...
W/s.quick_answer(24240): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
I/ProviderInstaller(24240): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
W/Firestore(24240): (24.2.2) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds
W/Firestore(24240): 
W/Firestore(24240): This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
W/Firestore(24240): (24.2.2) [WatchStream]: (60a1739) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Channel shutdownNow invoked, cause=null}.
W/DynamiteModule(24240): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule(24240): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller(24240): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
```

note: I have made all configurations to connect with firebase and initialize the firebase app successfully without any problem...

Comment: are you trying to build it to emulator or real device?

Comment: i have tried both, and same problem